# Unable to set either CSS style or style HTML attribute directly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and all tables seem to be borderless as far as I can see.

When I check it with Firebug I can disable css initialization for `<table>` element and design seems to be OK. Firebug tells me the CSS code is set in theme's style.css file. I open the file and check the content but there is no such line.

After this I choose a worse way to manually set the `style` attribute of my `<table>` HRTML element as follows. I also apply **!important** directive to override anything.

[image]

As far as I can know the `style` attribute of an HTML element overrides all CSS and previous (inherited or not inherited) style declarations. Also the **!important** also makes it undestructable. I have used both I still can not make it work.

What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Regards.

P.S. : You can check the faulty content @ http://pmiturkey.org/hakkimizda/uyelik/

The table as the bottom of the content.

Comment: Is your wordpress site live? Can you share the URL?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the content to display the link to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I played a little with firebug in your website here and had to do a few things:

1) Remove border="1" in that same table

2) Change from style="1 border #000 !important;" to style="1px border #000;"

These changes solve your problem.

**EDIT**

In order to draw borders around each cell of the table instead, proceed as follows:

1) Remove the table's style attribute

2) In your css file, add the following:

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This should add borders around each table cell of yours. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've just seen in a comment of yours that your main goal is to draw borders in table cells as well. Will update my answer with this "bonus".

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The wierd thing is I have added the line at tha bottom of the CSS file and uploaded it to site. When I download back the file I can see the line. But when I display the page and debug with Firebug and locate the style.css file I can not see the new lines at the end? As far as I upload it directly to the site why does not the changes apply directly?

Comment: Your browser is probably loading an old CSS file that was in cache. Try reloading your browser using Ctrl + Shift + R. If this does not work, try cleaning your browser's cache or accessing your website with another browser that you haven't used for some time.

Comment: Well I was trying Ctrl+F5, but also I think I have figured another walkaround. I have added `<style type="text/css">
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>` at the start of the page. And it worked :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and efforts.

Comment: You are welcome! But I'm still pretty sure that this is something related to browser's cache. I used to struggle with this a lot when it came to CSS, JS or image files' older versions stuck in cache.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you aren't adding a color to your border `border: 1px solid red;`.  The borders are probably being removed in a css reset.  You can add css to the bottom of your styles.css file and that should override any reset.

Also.. are you wanting a border around the table, or a border between the table rows?  You might want to specify what exactly you want.

Comment: I actually want to draw all borders around and in the table. But since I have failed so far I have been trying to start from the very basics.